# Java NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale) inconsistent for negativePrefix

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, utf

Trying to format negative number to String using:

```
(DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("no")));
```

Using jdk-10.0.2. I have found out that Norway and some other countries are using Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212) for negative prefix, while most other countries are using Unicode Character 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D). This is a problem as tests are failing on `.isEqualTo` and on my Mac negative prefix is always HYPHEN-MINUS.

A solution I have found is to call `setNegativePrefix("-")` after getting the DecimalFormat to override the strange local negative prefixes.

Please also see workaround at Orcale (end of page) https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8214926.

```
@Test
public void norwegianNegativePrefixDifferentFromEnglish() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Assertions.assertThat(((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("no"))).getNegativePrefix())
            .isEqualTo(((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en"))).getNegativePrefix());
}
```

Anyone know why? Executing this Java gives the attached results:

```
    public void fintLocals() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> negativeSignAndLocals = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        DecimalFormat formatForLocal = ((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale));
        // System.out.println(formatForLocal.getNegativePrefix()+ " minus for "+locale);
        List<String> negLoc = negativeSignAndLocals.get(formatForLocal.getNegativePrefix());
        if (negLoc == null) {
            negativeSignAndLocals.put(formatForLocal.getNegativePrefix(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        negativeSignAndLocals.get(formatForLocal.getNegativePrefix()).add(locale.toString());
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : negativeSignAndLocals.entrySet()) {

        System.out.println("Negative sign = " + entry.getKey() + " as Hex value " + charToHex(entry.getKey().charAt(0))
                + " is used by: " + (String) String.join(",", entry.getValue()));
    }
}

static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
    // Returns hex String representation of byte b
    char hexDigit[] = {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
    };
    char[] array = {hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f]};
    return new String(array);
}

static public String charToHex(char c) {
    // Returns hex String representation of char c
    byte hi = (byte) (c >>> 8);
    byte lo = (byte) (c & 0xff);
    return byteToHex(hi) + byteToHex(lo);
}
```

Negative sign − as Hex value 2212 is used by: nn,sv_SE,sv,se_NO,nb_SJ,no_NO_NY,sv_FI,no,ksh,gsw_CH,et,gsw,gsw_FR,fi,et_EE,rm,nb_NO,fi_FI,rm_CH,ksh_DE,se_FI,no_NO,lt_LT,nn_NO,se_SE,se,fo_DK,fo_FO,fo,lt,gsw_LI,sv_AX,nb

Negative sign - as Hex value 002d is used by: ,bg,kea,zu,am_ET,fr_DZ,ti_ET,bo_CN,hsb,qu_EC,ta_SG,lv,en_NU,zh_SG_#Hans,en_MS,en_GG,en_JM,vo,kkj,sr_ME,es_BO,dz_BT,mer,sah,en_ZM,fr_ML,br,ha_NG,bs_BA,dsb_DE,sk,os_GE,ml,en_MT,en_LR,en_GH,en_IL,cs,el,tzm_MA,af,sw_UG,ses_ML,smn,tk_TM,sr_ME_#Cyrl,dsb,lkt_US,vai_LR_#Latn,ji_001,yo_NG,khq,sw_CD,vo_001,en_PW,pl_PL,fil_PH,sr_CS,ne_IN,es_PH,es_ES,es_CO,bg_BG,ji,bs_BA_#Latn,en_VC,es_US,agq,hsb_DE,en_US_POSIX,en_150,en_KN,ha_NE,pt_MO,ebu,ro_RO,zh__#Hans,lb_LU,sr_ME_#Latn,es_GT,so_KE,dje_NE,bas_CM,fr_PM,fr_MG,es_CL,mn,agq_CM,kam_KE,teo,tr_TR,eu,en_MO,shi__#Tfng,en_BZ,sq_AL,es_DO,ru,twq_NE,az,nmg_CM,kl_GL,en_NR,nd,kk,az__#Cyrl,en_MP,en_GD,tk,hy,shi__#Latn,en_BW,en_AU,en_CY,kab_DZ,kde_TZ,ta_MY,ti_ER,nus_SS,en_RW,nd_ZW,ksb,luo,lb,ne,en_IE,zh_SG,ln_CD,en_KI,nnh_CM,om_ET,ja_JP,my,ka,mgh,or_IN,fr_MF,shi,kl,yue_HK,en_SZ,rwk_TZ,zh,es_PE,mgh_MZ,saq,az__#Latn,ta,en_GB,lag,zh_HK_#Hant,ksf_CM,bo,kk_KZ,es_PA,om_KE,en_AS,fr_VU,zh_TW,bez,kln,fr_MC,kw,pt_MZ,fr_NE,vai__#Latn,ksb_TZ,ln,en_JE,ln_CF,uz_AF,en_CX,luy_KE,pt,en_AT,gl,kkj_CM,sr__#Cyrl,es_GQ,kn_IN,to,en_SX,ga,qu,ru_KZ,en_TZ,en_PR,mua,ko_KP,in,sn,nl_SR,rof,en_BS,km,zgh,fr_NC,be,gv,es,dua,gd_GB,jgo,nl_BQ,fr_CM,uz_UZ_#Cyrl,pa_IN_#Guru,en_KE,guz,mfe,asa_TZ,teo_UG,ja,fr_SN,or,brx,fr_MA,pt_LU,fr_BL,en_NL,mgo_CM,ln_CG,te,az_AZ,sl,ko_KR,el_CY,mr_IN,ha,es_MX,es_HN,hu_HU,ff_SN,sbp,sq_MK,sr_BA_#Cyrl,uz,bs__#Cyrl,sr__#Latn,en_SS,sw,bo_IN,fy_NL,tr_CY,nmg,en_MG,fr_BI,shi_MA,uz_UZ_#Latn,bn,dua_CM,vai__#Vaii,kn,fr_TN,sr_RS,de_CH,bn_BD,nnh,fr_PF,en_ZA,gu,pt_GQ,vun_TZ,jmc_TZ,en_TV,lo,fr_FR,en_PN,pa_IN,en_MH,fr_BJ,vai_LR,zh__#Hant,cu_RU,zh_HK_#Hans,nl_NL,sah_RU,en_GY,bs__#Latn,ky,mas,dyo_SN,os,bs_BA_#Cyrl,nl_CW,sk_SK,pt_CH,fr_GQ,ff_CM,am,en_NG,fr_CI,ki_KE,en_PK,zh_CN,en_LC,rw,brx_IN,gv_IM,mk_MK,en_TT,dav,sl_SI,fr_HT,te_IN,nl_SX,ses,ce,fr_CG,fr_BE,jgo_CM,mt_MT,es_VE,mg,mr,mer_KE,ko,en_BM,ak,seh,kde,dz,kea_CV,mgo,vi_VN,en_VU,en_US,to_TO,mfe_MU,seh_MZ,fr_BF,pa__#Guru,it_SM,fr_YT,gu_IN,ii_CN,ast,fr_RE,ca_FR,sr_BA_#Latn,bn_IN,fr_GP,pa,zgh_MA,uk_UA,fr_DJ,rn,rwk,hu,fr_CH,en_NF,twq,ha_GH,sr_XK_#Cyrl,bm,en_GU,nl_AW,de_BE,en_AI,en_CM,xog_UG,cs_CZ,tr,ca_ES,cgg,nyn_UG,ru_MD,ms_MY,ta_LK,ksf,en_TO,cy,en_PG,fr_CF,pt_TL,sq,fr,en_ER,qu_PE,sr_BA,es_PY,de,es_EC,kok_IN,lg_UG,zu_ZA,fr_TG,sr_XK_#Latn,en_PH,ig_NG,fr_GN,prg_001,cgg_UG,zh_MO_#Hans,lg,ru_RU,ff,en_DM,en_CK,ga_IE,en_BI,en_AG,fr_TD,en_WS,fr_LU,ebu_KE,bem_ZM,xog,ewo_CM,fr_CD,so,rn_BI,en_NA,kab,ms,nus,sn_ZW,prg,ug,es_EA,th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai,hi,fr_SC,ca_IT,lag_TZ,en_SL,teo_KE,ca_AD,zh_MO_#Hant,en_SH,vai,qu_BO,haw_US,vi,fr_CA,de_LU,sq_XK,dyo,en_KY,mt,it_CH,de_DE,si_LK,luo_KE,en_DK,yav,so_DJ,it_IT,eo,kam,en_ZW,ro,eo_001,ee,en_UM,fr_MU,pl,en_TK,en_SI,mua_CM,vai_LR_#Vaii,saq_KE,pt_GW,lo_LA,chr,af_ZA,ms_SG,ee_TG,ln_AO,be_BY,ff_GN,in_ID,hr_HR,luy,as,rof_TZ,it,pt_CV,uk,my_MM,mn_MN,da_DK,en_FM,es_PR,wae_CH,en_BE,ii,fr_WF,ru_BY,naq,en_SG,ee_GH,kln_KE,tzm,fur,om,hi_IN,en_CH,asa,yo_BJ,ast_ES,fr_KM,bez_TZ,fr_MQ,en_SD,es_AR,en_MY,ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese,es_SV,pt_BR,ml_IN,sbp_TZ,fil,en_FK,uz__#Cyrl,is_IS,hy_AM,en_GM,en_DG,ne_NP,hr,pt_ST,ak_GH,fur_IT,ta_IN,en_SE,fr_GF,lkt,zh_CN_#Hans,is,es_419,si,pt_AO,en_001,en,guz_KE,es_IC,ca,ru_KG,fr_MR,zh_TW_#Hant,bm_ML,pa_PK,kw_GB,ug_CN,as_IN,es_BR,zh_HK,khq_ML,sw_KE,en_SB,th_TH,rw_RW,chr_US,shi_MA_#Tfng,nyn,yue,jmc,en_MW,naq_NA,mk,en_IO,en_DE,en_CC,bs,ro_MD,en_FI,pt_PT,fy,az_AZ_#Cyrl,th,dav_KE,uz_UZ,shi_MA_#Latn,es_CU,en_SC,en_VI,haw,eu_ES,en_UG,en_NZ,dje,es_UY,bas,mas_KE,ru_UA,sg_CF,el_GR,yav_CM,uz__#Latn,sg,da_GL,en_FJ,de_LI,en_BB,km_KH,smn_FI,hr_BA,de_AT,nl,lu_CD,ca_ES_VALENCIA,so_SO,lv_LV,es_CR,fr_GA,sr,sr_RS_#Cyrl,bem,en_MU,da,wae,gl_ES,en_IM,az_AZ_#Latn,en_LS,ig,en_HK,en_GI,ce_RU,en_CA,gd,ka_GE,fr_SY,sw_TZ,fr_RW,so_ET,nl_BE,mg_MG,cy_GB,en_VG,cu,os_RU,sr_RS_#Latn,en_TC,ky_KG,af_NA,vun,en_IN,lu,ki,yo,es_NI,ff_MR,mas_TZ,ti,kok,ewo,ms_BN,br_FR

Negative sign ‎ as Hex value 200e is used by: fa_AF,ar_EH,fa_IR,ar_MR,fa,ur_IN,ps,lrc_IR,lrc_IQ,ps_AF,ar_DZ,iw,lrc,pa_PK_#Arab,ar_MA,iw_IL,ur,uz__#Arab,ar_LB,ks_IN,ur_PK,mzn,mzn_IR,uz_AF_#Arab,ar_TN,ks,pa__#Arab,ar_LY

Negative sign ‏ as Hex value 200f is used by: ar_JO,ar_SA,ar_TD,ar_EG,ar_SD,ar_KM,ar_IL,ar_SY,ar_PS,ar_YE,ar_OM,ar_SS,ar_ER,ar_SO,ar_AE,ar_BH,ar_IQ,ar_QA,ckb_IQ,ar,ckb_IR,ar_001,ckb,ar_KW,ar_DJ

Comment: The difference in equal signs where introduced with java 10, in java 8 they were similar

Comment: I don't think anybody other than the developers of Java can answer a question like "Why". And it doesn't help you anyway - you are stuck with the situation whether it is justifiable or not. Perhaps you'd prefer to change your question to something practical like how to go around this issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks for input, I probably used Stack overflow a bit wrong here but I thought it was so strange that maybe I did something wrong. I have gotten around it a bit ugly but will update my question with it.

Comment: Another workaround is to use "-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR" as a JDK parameter. This tells Java to use the old way for locale spesific formatting.

Comment: There is probably a bug in the code above as `U+200E` is `LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK` and `U+200F` is `RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK`. Both bidi formatting control characters and not negative signs. My guess is that those locales use muti-character string for their negative signs and the code assumes a single character is always used so only reports the first character in the negative sign string.

Comment: Thanks for good comment and you are probably correct. But still strange that negative sign changed from Java 8 to 11? But I might be terrible wrong here due to little traffic on this issue:-)